# Trying to draw an ellipse, all i get is a line

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to draw an ellipse and cannot get anything more than a line.[image]

Comment: Make sure that the fill color's alpha value is set to the maximum value. Also, try if it helps to click on the button for 'making ellipse whole' - the rightmost button in the tool controls bar, that looks like a full circle.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have no Stroke Paint applied.

Hit the *Flat Colour* button, and choose a colour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The node indicators would lead one to believe that you have drawn an ellipse. The stroke palette shows undefined stroke color. When I create an ellipse, it defaults to my last stroke paint, but if I turn it to "undefined" the result is a blank area.

Consider to provide/select a stroke paint color and size in your screen shot to further troubleshoot, if that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not properly related to the stroke color: you have an **arc of ellipse**, so little to seem invisible (Start: 0.000, End: 0.371).

The case is the following:

[image: little arc of ellipse]

You can change the angle of the arc by dragging the **[handles](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Arcs.html)** or by a direct input of the value in the fields **Start**, **End**:

[image: ellipse with a bigger angle]

Or, if you prefer, you can also **close the arc**, obtaining a **whole ellipse**, by clicking the reset button in the *Tool controls* bar (the bar appears if you press the button to draw the ellipses):

[image: closed ellipse]

Of course, if you set a stroke color you see the border of the path:

[image: little arc of ellipse, with stroke]